# javascript how to use smoke.js with onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, alert, onbeforeunload

i am using [smoke.js](http://ssssnakes.com/smoke/) to create some neat alerts :)

the problem comes when i try to use it on the `onbeforeunload` event.

i place it like this:

```
<body onbeforeunload="javascript:tstconfirm();">
```

but looks like the script gets unloaded or something because the script doesn't work.

if i try:

```
<body onbeforeunload="javascript:alert('test');">
```

the alert works.

any ideas on how to fix this ?

thanks

Comment: Where is the `tstconfirm` function coming from? I couldn't find it on the smoke.js website.

Comment: created a dummy function tstconfirm and tested in jsfiddle, it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/AAJwS/1/

Comment: `alert` is a blocking call. The `alert` can show up onbeforeunload since the browser will wait for it. Smoke.js alerts get rendered in the dom, but can not block the way `alert` does. They may get rendered, but the browser will continue to unload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $(".black").css('display', 'block');
         // or do something else
        }, 1000);
    },1);
    return 'Wait! Save up to $20 Today!';
});
});
</script>
```